# Master page containing User Control with AutoCompleteExtender

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ajax

**Brief of Application:**

I am creating a website which has a master page , a sub master page and some content pages.

I have created some user controls to display information on the main master page. I have registered those controls directly on my main master page and have specified their position.

I have used some content pages and other master page in ContentPlaceHolder.

**Description:**

I have a textbox on one of my user control, which i want to use with AutoCompleteExtender to help the user in finding the specific text by displaying him the related results.

Here is the sample piece of code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TxtSource" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:AutoCompleteExtender
    ID="AutoCompleteSource" 
    TargetControlID = "TxtSource"
    MinimumPrefixLength="1"
    ServiceMethod="GetSourceList" 
    runat="server" UseContextKey="True">
</asp:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

Code Behind of Custom Control:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod(), System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
public static string[] GetSourceList(string prefixText, int count, string contextKey)
{
    string[] SourceList = {"Star Wars", "Star Trek", "Superman", "Memento", "Shrek", "Shrek II"};  

    return (from m in SourceList where m.StartsWith(prefixText.ToUpper()) select m).ToArray(); 
}
```

I am not using the webservice but the codebehind to call the method.

**Issue:**

The function in codebehind is never called.

I am aware of the fact that i have to keep the function in aspx file, but with my bad luck i am not adding the control on aspx file but on master file and master page is again treated as a control and not the page.

One solution :

> I can add the custom control on every content page.

Problem :

> 1) No code re-usability, which i want to achieve.
>
> 2) Page layout will be changed.

Can there be any other solution, with least code changes?

Comment: try ServiceMethod="yourPage.aspx/GetSourceList"

Comment: @kobe i was not able to understand, what were you trying to say. But when FreddieH pointed me to a .cs class i came to know what should i do. Your point was also correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set the ServicePath of your autocomplete extender.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TxtSource" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:AutoCompleteExtender
    ID="AutoCompleteSource" 
    TargetControlID = "TxtSource"
    MinimumPrefixLength="1"
    ServiceMethod="GetSourceList"
    ServicePath="yourpage.cs" 
    runat="server" UseContextKey="True">
</asp:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

Comment: hey...thanks...that worked. Initially i was thinking that i can write the codebehind code in ascx.cs only. But that worked too.